# How to find tables with no foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, data-dictionary

Is there a query or command that shows which tables have no foreign keys?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could query the information schema:

```
SELECT table_schema, table_name
FROM   information_schema.tables t
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                   FROM   table_constraints tc
                   WHERE  t.table_schema = tc.table_schema AND
                          t.table_name = tc.table_name AND
                          tc.constraint_type = 'FOREIGN KEY')
```

Comment: Thank you, it works, but why is it taking over 10 seconds to run this?